# 4-pin audio jack does not work on ACER Aspire-ES1-512-C67E with Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: sound, acer, headphones, microphone, audio-jack

I have an audio jack on my computer(ACER Aspire-ES1-512-C67E) which was working with a 4-pin audio jack on Windows, but is not working on Ubuntu 19.10 :'(.

The problem is: there's a mic attached to my headphones, but the OS doesn't seem to notice them.

Does anyone have any idea on how to make it work?